# Turn an XML sequence of attribute values into a string?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Using xquery 1.0, I want to take a sequence like this;

```
<foo xml:id="x20"/>
<foo xml:id="x47"/>
<foo xml:id="x3"/>
```

And collate the ids into a string to put in an attribute of a new element like this;

```
<bar ids="x20 x47 x3"/>
```

Is there a way to do it without manually iterating over the input sequence using a FLWOR?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the simplest and shortest solution so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let $s := (<foo xml:id="x20"/>,<foo xml:id="x47"/>,<foo xml:id="x3"/>)
return <bar ids="{$s/@xml:id}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
<bar ids="{/*/*/@xml:id}"/>
```

**When this XQuery is applied on the following XML document** (just wrapping the provided XML fragment into a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
  <foo xml:id="x20"/>
  <foo xml:id="x47"/>
  <foo xml:id="x3"/>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<bar ids="x20 x47 x3"/>
```